# Node.js/Socket.io not returning results in IE, using a secure connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, express

I have successfully implemented socket.io, node.js and express to server realtime json data to all browsers except IE (testing on 9) using a secure connection. This worked fine everywhere until I moved it behind https. From the server console output, it shows that an event is received when called from IE:

```
xhr-polling received data packet 5:::{"name":"lookup_place","args":
[{"place":"Berlin"}]}
```

However, no response is given and the next 4 lines shown in the console are:

```
clearing poll timeout
xhr-polling writing 8::
set close timeout for client 27081179790885432
xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration
```

When the same is done from FF or Chrome, the line "xhr-polling writing 8::" is appended with the correct response, for example:

```
xhr-polling writing 5:::{"name":"place_results","args":[{"a":
    [{"identifier":"52156","value":"Monschau, 52156"},
{"identifier":"67590","value":"Monsheim, 67590"},
{"identifier":"04617","value":"Monstab, 04617"}]}]}
```

I am using node.js version 0.4.10, socket.io version 0.7.7 and express version 2.4.3. The same scripts worked perfectly fine in IE 7-9 without an https/ssl/secure connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in discovering why no response is delivered in IE but works fine in all others.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug. I would advice you to fill an issue at [Socket.io's github issue page](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/issues). Then the authors will also receive an email and probably respond pretty fast.